# How to create dynamic rows/cloumn in tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind 3

The template that I want is this:

[image]

How can I create that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tailwind break points to start to accomplish this.

For example using this syntax `lg:red xl:blue` would dynamically change the colour on those specific breakpoints.

Here are the docs explaning in greater detail: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-a-single-breakpoint